# display array data in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

i'm trying to learn angular after a long time with react and i want to display data from an array.

I want to use a dropdown menu to select the id and to display the address of the selcted id.

The select code should look like this i guess

```
<select name="customer" >
  <option *ngFor='let customer of customers'>
    {{ customer.id }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Here is a array example

```
export interface Customer {
  id: number,
  companyName: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  street: string,
  streetNumber: number,
  zipCode: number,
  city: string,
  country: string,
}

export const customers = [
  {
    id: 800001,
    companyName: 'example company 1',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    street: 'Example Street',
    streetNumber: 7,
    zipCode: 11111,
    city: 'example city',
    country: 'example country'
  }
  {
    id: 800002,
    companyName: 'example company 2',
    firstName: 'Jessica',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    street: 'Example Street',
    streetNumber: 8,
    zipCode: 11111,
    city: 'example city',
    country: 'example country'
  }
  {
    id: 800003,
    companyName: 'example company 3',
    firstName: 'Mark',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    street: 'Example Street',
    streetNumber: 69,
    zipCode: 11111,
    city: 'example city',
    country: 'example country'
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you forget to mention the question/problem faced in the post.

Comment: i just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

In angular, to use variables in .ts in the .html we use, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#more-on-template-syntax):

1. Interpolation, e.g.

   ```
   {{variable}}
   ```
2. Binding syntax,e.g.

   ```
   <input [value]="variable">
   ```
3. Two way binding,e.g.

   ```
   <input [(ngModel)]="variable">
   ```
4. Built-in-directives (*ngFor, *ngIf...),e.g.

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3]>{{item}}</div>
   ```
5. Others object like Reactive Forms
6. ...

I can say the response to your question

```
<select [(ngModel)]="customer" >
  <option *ngFor='let item of customers' [ngValue]="item">
    {{ customer.id }}
  </option>
</select>
{{customer|json}}
```

But I recommended, make a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) to learn how Angular works (You can skip the animations parts -for me the more complex-)